# Does Server Collection Create A Seperate LOH Heap For Each Core? C#

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

From the research On Garbage Collection, Server Collection Allows for the creation of a separate thread for each CPU core that you have that runs a separate GC and Generational Heap. But I Wasn't Able to find anything On whether each thread gets its own LOH Heap Or There Is Just One LOH Heap Per App

Comment: When asking a detailed technical question, terminology is important. I've been staring at your use of _"Server Collection"_ trying to figure out what you are talking about (most collections have nothing to do with the LOH). It's only when the answer popped up that I realized you meant the _Server Garbage Collection_ system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question. It seems it does maintain a *heap* (small and large) per *logical CPU*, though ***not*** per thread. Which makes a lot of sense :)

[Workstation and server garbage collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/workstation-server-gc)

> **Server GC**
>
> The following are threading and performance considerations for server garbage collection:
>
> ...
>
> - A heap and a dedicated thread to perform garbage collection are provided **for each logical CPU**, and the heaps are collected at the same time. Each heap contains **a small object heap and a large object heap**, and all heaps can be accessed by user code. Objects on different heaps can refer to each other.